# Display single variables above a chart in matplotlib/python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display the keys and values of a dictionary directly above the chart, just as [yahoo finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bc?s=XOM%20Basic%20Chart) does for the date price and after hours quotes exc.

Example dictionary:

```
d = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2','key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}
```

How can I display all the Key and values in the dictionary above a chart using `matplotlib plt` and `python`?

Comment: What do you mean by "above a chart"? In the title? Be more specific please.

Comment: @Christian will do lemme edit it

Comment: [This would be helpful](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html#basic-text-commands), maybe use `annotate` or `figtext`.

Comment: @Christian Now that I see his pointer to yahoo finance, it appears that he wants to use suptitle from the reference that you gave and just put in the latest entry rather than the entry for each element.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function such as autolabel. The example puts the value above each bar element in a bar chart. [api example code: barchart_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

```
def autolabel(self,ax, mybar):
'''
Label each bar with the particular value

@parameter ax - The subplot being processed
@parameter mybar - The bars in the graph that must be labeled
'''

for rect in mybar:
  # Determine the actual height
  height = rect.get_height()
  pos = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.
  ax.text(pos, 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height), ha='center', va='bottom', \
          rotation='vertical', color='r')
return
```

Comment: This just prints it directly above the bars, but not above the actual chart, but it is a starting point for me to look into along with the features Christian mentioned above

Comment: The example code also dicusses adding legends to the chart. You might try examining that as well.